# Example of Click Map is not working for me

Tags: html, canvas

Sorry by this dummy question! :D

I´m trying to make a clickable map with html5 canvas element, I find this good example: http://www.rubydesigner.com/blog/click-map-using-html5-canvas

But when a download it (CTRL+S) from Chrome it doesnt work. It download the html page and files folder with the JS a images, I checked the path to the images, but still the map doesnt appear. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried other browsers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Initial assumption about CORS turns out to not be the case here.

The code seemed to work in Chrome and although CORS typically is the cause when downloading files and using canvas with local (file://) file references. As localhost is used here via XAMMP this won't be the cause and it turns out there are more than one bugs in the online code.

Specifically the way it calculates the coordinates for the mouse:

```
var datapos = ((e.offsetY-2) * 300 * 4) + ((e.offsetX-1) * 4);
```

This will result in a `NaN` value due to `offsetX/Y` which of course cannot be used for any index.

The more appropriate way is something like this, here also compensating for canvas offset:

```
var rect = map_wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
var datapos = ((e.clientY - (rect.top |0)) * 300 * 4) +
              ((e.clientX - (rect.left|0)) * 4);
```

However, I have never came across a floating point position for an element which seem to be case here (rect.top shows a float value in my browser, another little surprise) and therefor I am forcing the value to integer here (normally not necessarily.. I didn't dig deep into this). As debugging the whole code is a bit out of the scope here I will leave it with that and to OP to locate other bugs.

Correcting the position will at least give a usable index for the pixel array which in turn will return a valid (not necessarily correct it turns out, which leave checking of image, tolerane in case gamma/color correction is applied....) value for the red component (still issues when testing but as said, it's a bit out of the scope to do a full debug and correction).

Hopefully this can lead you to where the other errors are. I did not go through the html etc.

Comment: I´m using XAMMP on Windows but still not working, but the function  getImageData is been executed: I add alert before and after and the subwindows appear.

Comment: @DiegoQuirós the function will execute but the result will be blank. Check in console if you get an security warning. How do you access the downloaded files (ie. double clicking them using file:// (see address bar) or going through XAMMP using localhost) ?

Comment: The below text with the name of the country (Germany,Austria, et) appear when I move the mouse above the canvas BUT the image is completely blank and every time I move the mouse the next error is launched: 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined localhost/mapa/:68
(anonymous function) localhost/mapa/:68
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i`

This is line 68:
`$("#map_wrapper").css("background-position", (countries[red][0])*(-300)+"px 0px").css("cursor","pointer");`

Comment: Ok @DiegoQuirós. I have located at least one bug in the code (see updated answer). There are several issues with this code and even with this single correction there will more issues. Hopefully this can lead you to others (or update this based on context).

Comment: I have no idea what that line makes! But I think it must be in this way:
var rect = map_wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
var datapos = ((e.clientX - (rect.left|0))  * 4) + ((e.clientY - (rect.top |0)) * 300 * 4);

The 300 must be in the Y axis. This way the red value is always valid except when the mouse is just above a boundary country, I supposed because the boundary line is not perfectly white.

There is still a bug, but I think I can manage it! This code http://jsfiddle.net/ajCPT/136/ It doesnt work on jsFiddle but works on FF and Chrome.

Thanks for all your help Ken!

Comment: @DiegoQuirós no problem. Yeah I mixed up Y and X when I got so focused on the property names. I'll update my answer, thanks ;)